# Timeout for javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).click(function () {        

jQuery('.close-news').css('display', function(){return jQuery('#colorbox').css('display');});
});
```

I have this script, which make my link appear\dissappear depends on state of #colorbox block. But somewhy link appear\dissappear not immediatelly, but after 2 click.
Basically i have to click one more time in random area to make my script work
I guess its because my html code isnt update fast enought to make . So how do i add some timeout for this script?

Comment: No, a timeout is not the solution in here. Show us the code that changes the state of #colorbox.

Comment: There is only minified version of code. But here is the website, im working on it: http://stagealpha.dyndns.org/supra/news
What i have to do, it to make link in bottom of site called Закрыть новость to show itself only when lightbox popped up, and hide it self when lightbox closed

Comment: You really need to edit the code that makes the lightbox appear, to show/hide the link as well. Everything else is nonsense. Why don't you have access to the source?

Comment: I can get access, but what exactly do i have to look for?

Comment: The code that lets the lightbox pop up / close, of course. Just add a line there to hide / show the link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Colorbox in Drupal.
There can be a callback function that gets executed once the Colorbox is shown up.
After Debugging your site, seems that there is a `cbox_complete` custom event firing up.
If thats the case, you can attach a function to this event.
In the function, you can toggle the display of your `.close-news` `li` element, similar to  what you are doing on document click in the question